# Writing a case-insensitive sort using qsort

Tags: c

I am trying to write a case-insensitive sort with qsort. However, I'm having trouble converting the `const void *` into a `const char *` to compare strings. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int case_insensitive_string_sort (const void * a, const void  *b) {

    int a_len = strlen(a);
    char a_char, b_char;
    printf("%d", a_len);

    for (int i=0; i<=a_len; i++) {
        a_char = tolower((char*) a[i]);
        b_char = tolower((char*) b[i]);
        if (a_char != b_char)
            return b_char - a_char;
    }

    return 0;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // example doing the comparison with known input to see if it works
    // int a = case_insensitive_string_sort("axxx", "ab");

    qsort(argv, argc, sizeof(argv[0]), case_insensitive_string_sort);
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
        printf("<%s>, ", argv[i]);

  }
```

How would I properly do that?

Comment: Note that your function is not a sort function; it is a comparison function or comparator that is usable by `qsort()`, though.  To sort using `qsort()`, you have to call it somewhere.  Your code doesn't do that.   You can't index a `void *` in standard C (regardless of whether GCC allows it or not), so `a[i]` etc isn't going to work.  The argument to `tolower()` should be an `int` value containing either `EOF` or an `unsigned char` value.  It should not be a `char *`.  If you are sorting an array of strings, then the arguments to the comparator will be of type `char **` converted to `void *`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question with actually doing a `qsort` -- though I'm not sure if that's correct or not.

Comment: If you're writing for a Unix system (POSIX or BSD), then your standard library should supply the `strcasecmp` function, which you could use instead of writing it from scratch.  Other systems might supply it as well.

Comment: why not use `stricmp`?

Comment: @phuclv: `stricmp()` is a Windows API and not a part of POSIX.  It may be available on some Unix-like platforms (but it isn't part of macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, for example, nor Linux, at least not Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), but `strcasecmp()` is the POSIX analogue to `stricmp()`.  The converse applies, I believe; `strcasecmp()` is not available on Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're certainly going to have trouble

> converting the `const void *` into a `const char *` to compare strings.

because the array you are sorting (`argv`) is an array of `char*`, not an array of `char`. And the comparison function used by `qsort` is provided with *pointers* to the objects being sorted, not the objects themselves. [Note 1]

So if your comparison function was receiving a `char *` (cast to `void *`), you would be comparing characters. Since you are in fact comparing character strings -- i.e., arrays of characters -- you should expect a `char**` (cast to `void*`).

One pretty ugly way of handling that would be:

```
> a_char = tolower(((char**) a)[i]);
```

But my preference is to cast the arguments once at the top of the function:

```
int my_compare(void* va, void* vb) {
  char** a = va;
  char** b = vb;
  /* ... */
}
```

I don't do that for efficiency; it probably produces the same code. I do it because I find it easier to read.

#### Notes

1. C doesn't have any way to pass an object of unknown type by value. But you can pass a *pointer* to an object of unknown type by casting the pointer to a `void*`, as long as the function being called has a way to know what the original type of the pointer was.

Comment: thanks for this. Could you please show the correct way to do the "tolower" line for the function to properly work?

Comment: @TagC198: Yeah, I was doing that. But really, you need to understand that pointers are a real thing in C, and things can be pointed at. So if `foo` has type `T[]`, then the type of `&foo[i]` ("the address of item `i` in `foo`") must be `T*`, and the fact that `T` is `char*` makes no difference to the algorithm.

Comment: (Also, converting character by character to lower case only works in some languages. In the general case, you need to convert the entire string to lower-case, or even better use a locale-aware comparison function.)

Comment: when I try that I get: `warning: initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'const void *' discards qualifiers`.

Comment: @TagC198: Yes, if you want to use `const void*`, you need `char*const*` (or `const char*const*`). I'll leave you to do the research about what the different locations of `const` mean. :-) But it has to do with the fact that `const void*` is expected to be a pointer to a constant thing, and `const char* str` Is not a constant thing. (It's a *pointer to* a constant thing.)